# Unable to fetch videos from JSON file in android and Images are repeating with different users

Tags: android, json

JSON CODE

```
{"posts":[{"post_id":"78","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-06-12 16:12:36","files":[{"file_name":"1497264156_IQ_Test___10_Most_Popular_Tricky_Questions.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"77","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-06-12 16:09:31","files":[{"file_name":"1497263971_41_Amazing_Inventions.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"76","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-06-12 15:29:52","files":[]},{"post_id":"75","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-06-12 15:25:08","files":[{"file_name":"1497261308_BAYWATCH__The_Invitation__Clip_(2017)_Priyanka_Chopra_Comedy_Movie_HD.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"74","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-06-12 15:16:44","files":[{"file_name":"1497260804_input.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"73","post_desc":"","firstname":"Abc","lastname":"Xyz","created_at":"2017-06-14 13:04:09","files":[{"file_name":"1497425649_1494931753_IMG_3919.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"72","post_desc":"","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-06-13 12:59:55","files":[{"file_name":"1497338995_likes-1.png","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"71","post_desc":"good afternoon....\u263a\ufe0f\u263a\ufe0f","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-06-13 12:58:43","files":[]},{"post_id":"70","post_desc":"Good Morning\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-06-08 10:58:26","files":[]},{"post_id":"69","post_desc":"","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-06-08 10:55:16","files":[{"file_name":"1496899516_WhatsApp Image 2017-06-06 at 1.19.28 PM.jpeg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"68","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-31 23:52:19","files":[{"file_name":"1496254939_FB_IMG_1495992247380.jpg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"67","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-31 23:52:03","files":[]},{"post_id":"66","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-31 17:01:01","files":[]},{"post_id":"65","post_desc":"test","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-31 13:05:28","files":[]},{"post_id":"64","post_desc":"make a wish,take a chance.make a change....","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-31 12:34:20","files":[{"file_name":"1496214260_pp.jpeg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"63","post_desc":"","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-31 11:52:17","files":[{"file_name":"1496211737_Screenshot_2017-05-30-14-35-14-838_lockscreen.png","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"62","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-31 11:14:55","files":[{"file_name":"1496209495_5180.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"61","post_desc":"\u201cThe secret of change\r\nis to focus all of your energy\r\nnot on fighting the old,\r\nbut on building the new.\u201d\r\n~\u00a0Dan Millman\u00a0","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-31 10:45:11","files":[]},{"post_id":"60","post_desc":"","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-31 10:43:53","files":[{"file_name":"1496207633_layout-2017-05-23-181707.png","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"59","post_desc":"","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-30 23:17:46","files":[{"file_name":"1496166466_IMG-20170529-WA0041.jpg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"58","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-30 12:12:36","files":[]},{"post_id":"57","post_desc":"Good Morning","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-30 11:29:43","files":[]},{"post_id":"56","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:50:49","files":[]},{"post_id":"55","post_desc":"","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:50:04","files":[]},{"post_id":"54","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:47:24","files":[{"file_name":"1495797444_IMG_20170522_191006_842.jpg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"53","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:45:18","files":[]},{"post_id":"52","post_desc":"","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:32:24","files":[]},{"post_id":"51","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-26 16:18:31","files":[]},{"post_id":"50","post_desc":"","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-23 17:37:19","files":[{"file_name":"1495541239_VID-20170518-WA0029.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"49","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-16 16:19:13","files":[{"file_name":"1494931753_IMG_3919.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"48","post_desc":"","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-05-16 15:09:32","files":[{"file_name":"1494927572_Technology in the Future.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"47","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-05-16 13:30:09","files":[{"file_name":"1494921609_Tom and Jerry - Little School Mouse.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"46","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-05-16 13:16:34","files":[{"file_name":"1494920794_Tubelight _ Official Teaser _ Salman Khan _ Kabir Khan.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"45","post_desc":"","firstname":"pankti","lastname":"shah","created_at":"2017-05-16 13:13:51","files":[{"file_name":"1494920631_small.mp4","file_type":"2"}]},{"post_id":"44","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-13 16:45:08","files":[{"file_name":"1494674108_IMG_4126.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"43","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-13 16:24:30","files":[{"file_name":"1494672870_IMG_4123.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"42","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-13 16:23:25","files":[{"file_name":"1494672805_IMG_4124.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"41","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-13 15:48:39","files":[{"file_name":"1494670719_IMG_4121.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"40","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 22:53:24","files":[{"file_name":"1494609804_IMG_4119.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"39","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 18:28:28","files":[{"file_name":"1494593908_IMG_4015.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"38","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 14:13:20","files":[{"file_name":"1494578600_IMG_4113.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"37","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 14:13:18","files":[{"file_name":"1494578598_IMG_4113.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"36","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 14:13:15","files":[{"file_name":"1494578595_IMG_4113.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"35","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 14:13:12","files":[{"file_name":"1494578592_IMG_4113.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"34","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-12 14:13:09","files":[{"file_name":"1494578589_IMG_4113.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"33","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:43:42","files":[{"file_name":"1494526422_IMG_3950.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"32","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:43:10","files":[{"file_name":"1494526390_IMG_3944.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"31","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:26:24","files":[{"file_name":"1494525384_IMG_3127.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"30","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:26:20","files":[{"file_name":"1494525380_IMG_3127.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"29","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:24:12","files":[{"file_name":"1494525252_IMG_2600.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"28","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:24:06","files":[{"file_name":"1494525246_IMG_2600.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"27","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:22:04","files":[{"file_name":"1494525124_IMG_3113.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"26","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:21:11","files":[{"file_name":"1494525071_1491304854804.jpeg","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"25","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:20:26","files":[{"file_name":"1494525026_IMG_4050.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"24","post_desc":"Ganesh Mahotsav 2016 ","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:20:01","files":[{"file_name":"1494525001_IMG_4045.PNG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"23","post_desc":"","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-11 23:19:03","files":[{"file_name":"1494524943_IMG_4016.JPG","file_type":"1"}]},{"post_id":"22","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0d\n","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-10 14:57:16","files":[]},{"post_id":"21","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0a\n","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-04 11:06:07","files":[]},{"post_id":"20","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0a\n","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-04 11:06:03","files":[]},{"post_id":"19","post_desc":"Good morning","firstname":"karan","lastname":"qq","created_at":"2017-05-04 11:05:27","files":[]},{"post_id":"18","post_desc":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Qtp42J9IOUo","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:39:53","files":[]},{"post_id":"17","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude1c","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:38:40","files":[]},{"post_id":"16","post_desc":"hi hello","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:35","files":[]},{"post_id":"15","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:19","files":[]},{"post_id":"14","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:17","files":[]},{"post_id":"13","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:17","files":[]},{"post_id":"12","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:16","files":[]},{"post_id":"11","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude34\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:16","files":[]},{"post_id":"10","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\u263a\ufe0f\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude01","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:30:14","files":[]},{"post_id":"9","post_desc":"Going to receive loads of money....","firstname":"Manish","lastname":"Amin","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:08:58","files":[]},{"post_id":"8","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:08:57","files":[]},{"post_id":"7","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:08:55","files":[]},{"post_id":"6","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02","firstname":"Abc","lastname":"Xyz","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:08:47","files":[]},{"post_id":"5","post_desc":"\ud83c\udfe1\ud83c\udfeb","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:05:40","files":[]},{"post_id":"4","post_desc":"\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\ude0a\ud83d\ude12\ud83d\udc2e\ud83d\ude48\ud83d\ude1c\ud83d\ude09\ud83d\ude03","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 16:02:21","files":[]},{"post_id":"3","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude12\ud83d\ude0a","firstname":"Rushin","lastname":"Patel","created_at":"2017-05-02 15:58:42","files":[]},{"post_id":"2","post_desc":"\ud83d\ude33\ud83d\ude33\ud83d\ude33","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-05-02 15:57:31","files":[]},{"post_id":"1","post_desc":"hii....good afternoon...\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04\ud83d\ude04","firstname":"jaxi","lastname":"chawda","created_at":"2017-05-02 15:55:49","files":[]}]}
```

Android Activity code

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_DATA = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/home_post_service.php";

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linaralayout1);

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Sample.this, Posts_DATA.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        data_sAervers = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();

    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        String filename = "";
                        String filetype = "";

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                            if (posts != null && posts.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject fileObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String fName = fileObj.getString("firstname");
                                    String created_at = fileObj.getString("created_at");
                                    String post_desc = fileObj.getString("post_desc");


                                    Log.e("Details", fName + "" + created_at + "" + post_desc );

                                    JSONArray files = fileObj.getJSONArray("files");
                                    if (files != null && files.length() > 0) {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++) {
                                            JSONObject Jsonfilename = files.getJSONObject(j);
                                            filename = Jsonfilename.getString("file_name");
                                            filetype = Jsonfilename.getString("file_type");
                                            filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/" + filename;
                                            Log.e("Files", "" + filename);
                                        }
                                    } else

                                    {
                                        filename = "";
                                        filetype = "";
                                    }

                                    Data_SAerver item = new Data_SAerver(fName, created_at, post_desc, filename, filetype
                                    );
                                    data_sAervers.add(item);
                                }

                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers, getApplicationContext());

                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

MyAdapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers, Context context) {
        this.data_sAervers = data_sAervers;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data_SAerver data_sAerver = data_sAervers.get(position);

        holder.firstname.setText(data_sAerver.getFirstname());
        holder.created_at.setText(data_sAerver.getCreated_at());
        holder.post_desc.setText(data_sAerver.getPost_desc());


        holder.filepathurl.setText(data_sAerver.getfilepath());

      //  holder.onlinefirstname.setText(data_sAerver.getOnlline_firstname());

        if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("1")) {
            holder.files.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context).load(data_sAerver.getfilepath()).resize(736, 1128).onlyScaleDown().into(holder.files);
            holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("2")) {
                holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.files.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data_sAervers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView firstname, commenttext;
        public TextView created_at;
        public TextView post_desc;
        public ImageView files;
        public LinearLayout comment_linear_layout;
        public TextView comment_btn;
        public TextView filepathurl;
        public TextView playvideo;

        public TextView onlinefirstname;
        Context con;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            filepathurl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.filepathurl);
            filepathurl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            playvideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
            firstname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            created_at = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.created_at);
            post_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            files = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_files);
            con = context;
            onlinefirstname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.online_user_firstname);

            SparkButton sparkButton = (SparkButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.star_button1);
            sparkButton.setChecked(false);
            comment_btn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
            comment_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(con, Popup_layout.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    con.startActivity(i);





                    playvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent play = new Intent(con, PlayVideo.class);
                            play.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            play.putExtra("url", "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/");
                            con.startActivity(play);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Data_SAvere Class

```
public class Data_SAerver {

    private  String file;
    private String firstname;
    private String created_at;
    private String post_desc;
    private String filepath;
    private String filetype;

    public Data_SAerver(String firstname, String created_at, String post_desc, String filepath, String filetype) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.post_desc = post_desc;
        this.filepath = filepath;
        this.filetype = filetype;
    }


    public String getfilepath() {
        return filepath;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }
    public String getPost_desc() {
        return post_desc;
    }
    public String getFiletype() {
        return filetype;
    }

    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

IMAGE BASE URL =

```
http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/
```

VIDEO BASE URl =

```
http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/
```

RecyclerView XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView

                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:contentDescription="image"
                                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linaralayout1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="vertical">


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:text="Hi,Karan.Tell your friends about your day."
                                    android:textColor="#2196fe"
                                    android:textSize="15sp" />


                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

VideoView XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

here i am not getting video from  json file and images are repeating with different users
 please help to solve this issue
Thankyou in advance

Comment: have you checked with postman?

Comment: yes using postman i m getting all values bt in andorid not getting @PriteshVadhiya

Comment: Anyone can help me pls its urgent !!! @PriteshVadhiya

Comment: your videos seems to wrong path: just added baseurl to one of video path http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/1497261308_BAYWATCH__The_Invitation__Clip_(2017)_Priyanka_Chopra_Comedy_Movie_HD.mp4 getting 404

Comment: http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/1494920631_small.mp4  But it will play same video with all user actually i want to play vide who post only like facebook concept @NareshRavva

Comment: u can see image url + filename here filename is means image name is attaching  with Base Url of image path @NareshRavva

Comment: R u getting wht i m saying @NareshRavva ??

Comment: so what you are not getting proper response/or any issue with adapter class? can u elaborate.

Comment: can u give me ur email id so i can mail u my project and apk file please run ands u can also understand exactly @NareshRavva

Comment: i m  making aap like same as fb and all data are fetch from JSON file @NareshRavva

Comment: nareshravva123@gmail.com

Comment: please check ur mail @NareshRavva

Answer (score 0):

remove video click listener from viewholder class add in onBindViewHolder function it will work..

```
if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("1")) {
        holder.files.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(context).load(data_sAerver.getfilepath()).resize(736, 1128).onlyScaleDown().into(holder.files);
        holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (data_sAerver.getFiletype().equals("2")) {
            holder.playvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.files.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.playvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent play = new Intent(context, PlayVideo.class);
                    play.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    play.putExtra("url", data_sAerver.getfilepath());
                    context.startActivity(play);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: play.putExtra("url", "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/convert/" + FILE_Name);    FILE_Name giving error pls slove this @NareshRavva

Comment: play.putExtra("url", data_sAerver.getfilepath());

Comment: video path seems to be wrong http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/1497263971_41_Amazing_Inventions.mp4 just copy this google you will get an idea

Comment: actually videos are store in  uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/ in this path @NareshRavva

Comment: can u help me to fetch video as well as images from different BASE URL please @NareshRavva

Comment: if (filetype.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                                                //for videos
                                                filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/convert/" + filename;
                                            } else {
                                                //for images
                                                filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/" + filename;
                                            }

Comment: one issue is there images are repeating with different user if some post image its repeat with different user please fix this issue also @NareshRavva

Comment: ok if you got an answer for you question, add rigth mark for this answer, any others guys facing same issue, they can check this.

Comment: yes sure bt can u fix that problem whole posts are repeating with all users pls fix that problm thnx again @NareshRavva